# How to Embed a Google Form in Email in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-forms

I have a form that requires login and I am trying to fetch its html to embed in an email. Similar to the question [Google Apps Script: how to access or call "Send this form to others"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356234/google-apps-script-how-to-access-or-call-send-this-form-to-others)

```
var form = FormApp.create('New Form');
form.setRequireLogin(true);
...
var url = form.getPublishedUrl();
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(response).getContent();
    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
  });
...
```

Howerver, the URLFetchApp does not seem to have the correct OAuth configuration and I always get the HTML for Google Login page.

Is there a way to set the correct OAuth parameters to get the form HTML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question asks about the OAuth parameters required to allow `UrlFetch()` to obtain the HTML content of a form with `requiresLogin()` set. This answer doesn't address that directly.

Without requiring OAuth, you can briefly change the login requirement for the form, just long enough to grab the HTML from it. For a small amount of time, your form could be accessed by individuals outside of your domain, if they happened to have the URL, and filled the form fast enough to submit their response before you locked the form up again.

#### Script

The following `sendForm()` function will work for consumer & GApps domain accounts, whether or not `requiresLogin()` is set.

```js
/**
 * Send user an email containing the given form, in HTML.
 *
 * @param {Form}   form           Form object.
 * @param {String} email          One or more email addresses, comma separated.
 */
function sendForm(form,email) {
  var url = form.getPublishedUrl();

  // Temporarily disable requiresLogin so UrlFetch will operate
  if (form.requiresLogin()) {
    var requiresLogin = true;
    form.setRequireLogin(false);
  }

  // Fetch form's HTML
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(response).getContent();

  // Re-enable requireLogin, if necessary
  if (requiresLogin) {
    form.setRequireLogin(true);
  }

  var subject = form.getTitle();
  MailApp.sendEmail(email,
                    subject,
                    'This message requires HTML support to view.',
                    {
                      name: 'Form Emailer Script',
                      htmlBody: htmlBody
                    });
}
```

For completeness, here's a test function...

```js
function test_sendForm() {
  // Build new form for testing
  var form = FormApp.create('New Form');
  var formTitle = 'Form Name';
  form.setTitle(formTitle)
      .setDescription('Description of form')
      .setConfirmationMessage('Thanks for responding!')
      .setAllowResponseEdits(true)
      .setAcceptingResponses(true)

  // Require Login (for GApp Domain accounts only)
  try { 
    form.setRequireLogin(true);
  } catch (e) {
    // Error is expected for consumer accounts - carry on.
  }

  // Just one question
  form.addTextItem().setTitle("Q1");

  // Send it to self
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  sendForm(form,email)
}
```