# How to send a Google from via email through Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, embed, google-forms

Is there a way to embed a Google Form in an email that is sent through Google Apps Script?

I have tried the approach suggested on [Google Apps Script: how to access or call "Send this form to others"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356234/google-apps-script-how-to-access-or-call-send-this-form-to-others) but this doesn't show the form as you would send it directly from GoogleForms. The problem does not seem to be related to the email client however.

Comment: Please provide minimal, completed and verifiable code, have you tried reading this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028826/how-to-embed-a-google-form-in-email-in-google-app-script)?the ticket discuss about OAuth however you can apply the code offered by community. The code include `sendForm()` method to attach a Google Form in Email via apps script.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to 'embed' a google document/form/etc. in gmail is to actually send the URL as part of the gmail body. This is because google products only exist in the cloud, and therefore cannot be sent as a 'physical' copy.

When you send the url, the url will be in the message, but also a box will appear at the bottom of the received message with the normal thumbnail you are used to seeing.