# Send Form with MailApp after fetching html. Embed Google Form into email. Generated email contains only text

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I want to embed a Google form in an email and send it with MailApp. I'm attempting to use code found at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23671529/4305236:

```
var form = FormApp.create('New Form');
....
var url = form.getPublishedUrl();
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(response).getContent();
    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
  });
...
```

The logs show all the html for the form.

However, when I run the code, the email just looks like text, with the links at bottom. When I "show original" in the email, though, all that html for the form seems to be there, like in the log...

Would greatly appreciate any help.

**What generated form looks like, want this to be embedded in email:**
[image: What generated form looks like, want this to be embedded in email]

**What they are getting instead:**
[image: What they are getting instead]

Comment: What kind of output did you expect? Can you please add the screenshot of the email that you got?

Comment: @KENdi thanks, just added pics.

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60749897/3383907.

Copy/pasting for history purposes:

> When Google sends the form to folks directly and embeds the form in the email they are using their new offering called AMP. You can read more about it here:
>
> - https://developers.google.com/amp/
> - https://www.blog.google/products/g-suite/bringing-power-amp-gmail/
> - https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/
>
> The code you're using gets the raw HTML of the form as it would be rendered for a user in a browser. This code is not in AMP format. Ergo it will not do what you want.
>
> If you want that AMP experience you will need to create the AMP email yourself.
>
> I don't think [`FormApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) has a programatic way to send the form to folks, like you can from https://docs.google.com/forms/.
>
> I hope that helps.